# How to select a value from different row if the column is null in the current row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a decode statement in my select SQL like this -

```
...
decode(instr(col1,'str1'), 0, 'STR1', 'STR2') as NAME,
...
```

The problem is the col1 could be null.  So I thought I could use an inner decode like the following -

```
decode(instr(
  decode(col1, null, (
    select unique col1 from SAMETABLE st where st.pid = pid) as col2, col1), 'str1'), 0, 'STR1', 'STR2') as NAME,
```

But it failed.

Here is a possible snapshot of what in DB -

```
      col1       pid
row1  null       1
row2  somevalue  1
```

I would like to use the value of col1 in row2 to replace the value in row1 when col1 is null in row1 and the two records' pid are equal.

Can anyone point out if I'm doing something impossible?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you wanted to replace col1 with if you don't attach the full query. Also - you can consider using NVL to replace null values.

Comment: If there are multiple rows for that pid, which col1 value do you want to use? It might help to show some sample data and expected results. Also, "it failed" isn't helpful; please supply the error(s) you get or why the result is wrong.

Comment: Here is what the data could look like - 
row1 col1 pid
1       null  pid1
2       col_value  pid1
I would like to replace the null value by 'col_value' in the second row where the pid are equal

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and expected results (both in tabular format).

Comment: There will only ever be one non-null row per pid?

Answer (score 1):

There are the following issues with your code:

- You give the inner table an alias `st` and then do `where st.pid = pid`, but that is a self-reference, because also the other `pid` is taken from the table of the inner query. Instead, give the table in the main query an alias.
- You give the outcome of the inner query an alias (`as col2`), but giving aliases is not allowed inside expressions, so that needs to be removed.
- The inner query selects `unique col1`, but that can still give multiple results, which will give an error. The inner query must return exactly one value at all times (when there are different non null values, and even when there are none). So you should use an aggregate function, like `min`
- `decode(a, null, b, a)` is a long way to write `nvl(a, b)`

So you could use this:

```
select decode(
      instr(
        nvl(col1, (select min(col1) from t where pid = t1.pid)),
        'str1'
      ), 
      0, 'STR1', 'STR2'
    ) as NAME
from mytable t1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  I'll certainly try the nvl function.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back whether this answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in Oracle 11 g and it works pretty well. I have also tried to change the starting value of col1 and it works. So i guess you have some other issues that is related to the field type not on how DECODE works.

```
    DECLARE
    col1   VARCHAR(10);
    result VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN
      col1:=null;
        select DECODE(
                 instr(DECODE(col1, null, (select 'HELLO' from DUAL),
                              col1),'str1'), 0, 'STR1', 'STR2') into result  
        from  DUAL;
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(result);

     END
```

I guess you have to change the subquery :

```
select unique col1 from SAMETABLE st where st.pid = pid
```

with something like

```
select unique col1 from SAMETABLE st where st.pid = pid and col1 is not null
```

Comment: If there are more then 2 columns with the same pid you should use:
select min col1 from SAMETABLE st where st.pid = pid 
or
select col1 from SAMETABLE st where st.pid = pid and col1 is not null and rownum=1